# Replacement for C low level programming?

Tags: c, programming-languages

So C obviously has a pretty dominant low level programming stronghold.....but is anything coming out that challenges/wants to replace it?

Python/C#/etc all seem to be aimed at very high level, but when it comes down to nitty-gritty low level stuff C seems to be king and I haven't seen much "try" to replace that?

Is there anything out there, or does learning C for low level stuff seem to be the standard?

Comment: Can you clarify your question? What *exactly* do you mean by "low level stuff"? Is your question answered in [ *Are there any languages that fit the same niches as C?* ](http://StackOverflow.Com/q/3342213/#3342538) or maybe [ *What language is used to write operating systems (Windows)?* ](http://StackOverflow.Com/q/3317329/#3321433)?

Comment: I guess it would be the niches, I didn't really know what else to say tho.

Comment: V (but stil a bit buggy, golang-like), Zig (no built-in utf8), Nim (python-like), Pony, Rust (steep learning curve)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The recent trend is moving towards object oriented and managed languages - For example Symbian as an OS is entirely written in C++, Also Microsoft research has come with [Singularity OS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Singularity_%28operating_system%29) which is a managed programming model. The idea is that managed languages protect users from easy to make mistakes in C - like resource leaks, pointer corruptions etc by abstracting away these ideas. Also object oriented paradigm helps in writing easy to maintain code. For now C still rule the embedded world, however we can see that changing in coming decade, with more and more embedded world embracing C++ as the language of choice.

Comment: Right, cause you never get resource leaks or pointer corruption in C++ programs.

Comment: The difference between modularized C and C++ is almost completely syntaxual. The biggest gain I see isn't "OOP", but type safe templates. If you don't think C can be object oriented I suggest you look at the ffmpeg code base.

Comment: @EnabrenTane some of the things are really hard to achieve in C for example implementing auto_ptr in C! Here lies the power of C++ language in managing resources effectively.

Comment: Worth noting both systems referenced: Singularity OS & Symbian- are both practically dead.

Answer (score 6):

If you mean systems level then perhaps [D Language](http://www.digitalmars.com/d/).

Comment: D is not ready for it in many aspects

Comment: @MajesticRa the question was "...is anything coming out that challenges/wants to replace it?" ... not what language is ready in all aspects.  How about offering a few specifics or links as to why it's "not ready in many aspects" along with your down vote.

Comment: Please, don't be angry at me for down-vote your answer. My opinion, that "coming out" should refer to ready-to-use-today tool which could be just released in PRODUCTION but hasn't gathered the deserved attention yet. I know that D may look exactly like this from the first glance. But... I could write some 'link' and link it for you (there is not so much posts about D). I'll do it with time probably. But for now I suggest you to learn D better and try to plan a serious low-level/system PRODUCTION project. Recently I did so. REALLY thoroughly did. Do it yourself and you'll understand my concern.

Answer (score 3):

Well to be honest it depends on your need to be "low level"/"system level" and what the system is.

As Neera rightly points out, there is an increasing trend towards managed languages.

So, if you're writing application code, unless you're actually writing the algorithms and optimisations, the idea is that you use the managed code/higher level abstractions. The need to do low level stuff all the time is, on common platforms, vastly reduced. Anywhere you have access to an API that is anywhere near good, you're probably going to have nicer abstraction layers around.

However, if you're implementing on a new architecture, you can either: use assembly to produce a compiler for that platform or write a compiler that outputs machine code from that platform from another platform (cross compilation). Then you need to compile a compiler for that platform.

As you can imagine, C++ is harder to deal with than C in this regard. Even C is actually quite an effort to do well. I've heard people say they like stack based languages like [FORTH](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Forth_%28programming_language%29) because for basic work they can get it up and running with very little assembly (compared to a c compiler or full blown cross compilation effort).

Edit (because I like it) Here's a [link](http://git.annexia.org/?p=jonesforth.git;a=summary) to the [JonesForth](http://rwmj.wordpress.com/2010/08/07/jonesforth-git-repository/) git repository. Take a look. Jonesforth is an implementation of forth in i386 assembly complete with code comments walking you through the whole process.

Comment: +1 for Forth. I think the smallest Forth compiler is something like 30 *bytes*. (No, that is not a typo.) It probably doesn't get more low-level than that.

Comment: @Jorg I dug up the Jonesforth compiler/tutorial too... such a good piece of coding.

Answer (score 3):

Whatever happened to [Google's GO](http://code.google.com/p/go/)?

Comment: Gotta love how fast go-code compiles!  I like the language and it looks very promising but faces the usual hurdle of gaining some critical mass of acceptance.

Comment: Not really a low-level language in the manner C is.

Comment: The GC makes it a non-candidate to the C(at least on embedded)

Answer (score 3):

[LLVM](http://www.llvm.org/)

Answer (score 2):

C for low level stuff is standard. C works and its known. C is fast because it is low level and makes the programmer do lots of things that Python and C# do for you. You could write another language aimed to replace C, but I don't think it would get you anywhere except a slightly different syntax. (If you wanted to keep the speed of C).

Why is C so fast? Because its shiny assembler. For the things you need to do even faster you use YASM or inline assembler.

Comment: I once heard someone describe C as "the portable assembler".

Comment: Actually, with the recent advances in compiler technology, those features that were originally designed to make C fast (weak typing, not being memory-safe, pointer-safe or type-safe) have turned out to prevent advanced compiler optimization techniques such as Supercompilation, program fusion, map fusion, stream fusion and so forth, thus making C *slower* not faster. JVMs can now routinely compete with and sometimes even beat C, and they are getting faster at a rate that C compilers haven't been going for a long time. E.g., HotSpot has been getting faster 10-30 percent with every version.

Comment: You make great points. I look forward to the day my Ruby code is as fast as C :)

Answer (score 1):

There's actually quite a few things that can be used for low level programming. Here's some used in the past with advantages over C.

1. Pascal variants (used in GEMSOS)
2. Oberon (used in Oberson System and A2 Bluebottle)
3. Ada (used in safety critical projects and at least three OS's on limited hardware)
4. PL/0 (MULTICS)
5. Modula (used in CVSup and some academic projects for correct system software)
6. Smalltalk and Haskell were used for prototype OS's or OS replacement layers.
7. Cyclone, Popcorn, C0, and Typed Assembly Language do better than C while keeping much of it.

Additionally, languages with a runtime can be used if the lowest level parts are implemented by another language. Microsoft's Verve and the JX Operating System are examples. For an old school one, look up the Genera LISP Machine and it's "advantages." You still can't do much of that in modern systems development with C/C++ toolchains. ;)

So, even if C isn't totally replaceable, it's mostly replaceable in most situations without much performance loss. Have fun with these.

Answer (score 0):

I dont thing so
I like to use my old Assembly Rotines, but C is save

Answer (score 0):

I don't think C is low level enough. I would suggest assembly language. As far as I know, it's the lowest level a programmer could go. But you still have to deal with assembler, linker and loaders. There're still many detail things related to the target platform.

Answer (score 0):

There are platform specific low level languages, such as assembly languages and machine codes. With comparing these with C, C is rather high level language.

Answer (score 0):

What do you exactly mean by *low level*?

C is also used for *high level* stuff like user interfaces (the whole GNOME Desktop, and its library GTK are written in C).

---

I'd put C in the *low level* category because it lets you play with the actual machine (eg: raw memory addresses, just to cite something) adding only a really tiny abstraction layer.

Also other programming languages are offering a *clean* vision of the underlying machine:

- Many are derived from C and are compatible with it (C++, Objective-C). These supply some tools to ease your life by abstracting something. They could replace C, **but** if you'd use these languages, you'd lose compatibility: ObjectiveC and C++ interfaces cannot be used by C.
- Others belong to completely different families, and these, other than the above issue, cannot even use C stuff directly.

Thus, in my opinion, the main reason why C isn't dropped is for *commercial* reason (it would *cost* too much to write everything again so that everything is compatible to other languages), pretty much the same reason why COBOL still exists.

There are other reasons, like the fact that C is bare-bone, simple and fast to parse and compile and stuff, but in my opinion these are secondary.

---

Some big companies who can afford rewriting anything are however trying to kick C off (Apple is extensively using ObjectiveC, for example, while others are using C++).

I think that in future C will keep to exist, since there are no efforts in choosing a specific standard language to be used everywhere in place of C (if you write C code it'll work both with C, with C++ and with ObjectiveC systems, while the opposite is not true) and since there's a too vast code base of C code out there.